# C# PictureBox control flickering / performance issues

Tags: c#, winforms, scaling, picturebox

I am currently working in **Windows Form Apps** and am making what will essentially be a map editor for a game. The way i have gone about this is by having a central `TabControl` where each `TabPage` contains a custom `PictureBox` control and all the other UI controls are around this central `TabControl`. The `PictureBox` uses its Paint event to draw everything that is placed on the map, and therefore draws multiple images of many sizes, rotations and scales etc to the single `PictureBox`. This has all gone well so far. The `TabPage` is essentially used as a view window for the `PictureBox` and is of size (1280x720).

The problem is with the scale to which the maps are being produced. The avg (and also maximum) map size on screen is around *19200x10800px* and can be made up of hundreds of items at any one point. When drawing just a backdrop image of size *19200x10800px* the `PictureBox` starts to flicker when it redraws and makes the program unusable. As the map is so big you are able to pan around them and this is where the flickering really shows. Also i do not want to use a *19200x10800px* image source if possible for the sake of file sizes and the scaled image quality isn't an issue at all.

I have done heaps of reading on why this might be and feel like I have tried everything up until this point. So far ive tried:

- Having the background image only 1920x1080 and scaling it up by 10x
- Starting with a 1920x1080 image, programatically resizing it and drawing this image
- Slicing the background into multiple segments (i tried many different amounts) and drawing only the ones that the view window can see (tried this for both a small(1080p) and large(10800p) images)
- Using graphics clipping so that only the things on screen would be drawn
- Used Double Buffering on both the picturebox and the form that the picturebox is on
- Converting the image at initialisation to an "optimised bitmap" with faster formatting and then drawing the bitmap

I've probably tried a couple other things along with minor optimisations but its taken me so long ive forgotten the rest. From what i've read its most likely something to do with the control redrawing too slowly for some sort of performance reason or a limitation with picturebox's, however exactly what is going on i cannot tell due to lack of experience with form apps controls.

Currently to draw the background in the `Paint` event i have either:

```
g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(image.Size.Width * levelScale), (int)(image.Size.Height * levelScale)));
```

or

```
g.ScaleTransform(levelScale, levelScale);
g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(image.Size.Width), (int)(image.Size.Height)));
```

Where g is the `Graphics` object.

Have I hit the limit of Win form apps capabilities or is there something i may be missing?

Any and all help appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such a graphics intensive app is much better suited to WPF. PictureBox is notorious for similar issues.

Comment: You definitely hit the limit of Win form apps capabilities :O

Comment: Draw once to a `Image` member variable and assign that to PictureBox.Image. Then use a *IsDirty* bool to update/redraw the image when needed.

Comment: I think to use the power of hardware accelerator and directx right in UI Window, you should try some WPF solution. `Winforms` is not for such media and graphics intensive application. Of course there must be some way to reduce the flicker but it won't be the best solution. It looks like that your application involves gaming here, why don't you design all the GUI using DirectX or OpenGL to take advantage of the VGA power?

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. @KingKing The program is meant to be made in a short space of time and I would like something that does rapid prototyping if possible. Ive have never used WPF, DirectX or OpenGL directly so which would you suggest i should lean towards?

Comment: when i used to play with picturebox i usually had a picturebox for background and picturebox for above it and changed a little part of the background each time in order to avoid these flickering. and that was for small pictures in excellent hardware... maybe that'll help you

Comment: @WillBagley You can use WPF if possible, if you want to change the GUI completely (like in many games), you can use DirectX or OpenGL. Although learning them is not easy for a short time, I mean the learning curve is fairly steep.

Comment: You will need to show more code.  Using "g" in your snippet is a major Red Flag, that should always be "e.Graphics" in a Paint event handler.  Creating a Graphics object elsewhere will cause major flicker.

Comment: In answer to Hans, i havent included the line but for convenience sake at the start of my Paint i have g = e.Graphics. Also @HighCore i now know that there is no native support for it but is there any way i can utilise the tech of DirectX or OpenGL etc in winforms somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for formality I though id answer my own question just in case anyone else would like to know the outcome.

Based off the overwhelming consensus that winforms was just not made to do the things I was trying to do with it I decided I had to move to some other platform. Suggested to me was WPF, DirectX and OpenGL but after some extensive searching around I found what I think is the optimal solution.

In order to utilise the power of DirectX hardware acceleration MS has made it so that you can embed XNA graphics devices into a winforms application. Essentially you can create custom controls that run in the normal winform style that have access to a much higher caliber of graphics control. In this manner (with a bit of extra work) I have replaced the picturebox I was using with a custom graphics control which handles all of the drawing. This has worked very well, and on the up side i havent had to take too much of a hit to my development time.

For those looking for more info refer to [this](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) question which has further links that should help. Once again thanks to all those who gave their advice!

Answer (score 1):

This is a quoted answer from the URL at the bottom.  There are code examples at the link at the bottom.  Hope this is helpful; not sure if you tried this yet and maybe it'll help you get a little more juice out of the existing picturebox control.  As explain in the other answers, it sounds like you will be forced to a more powerful solution in the near future regardless (DirectX/OpenGL or WPF)

** Partial quote from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68ecd1f6-2eeb-45ce-a881-24c62145ab0e/c-picturebox-problems

"I'd guess the real problem is that it takes too long to redraw the images.  GDI+ is pretty slow, it doesn't use any video hardware acceleration.  To speed it up, be sure to avoid rescaling the drawing and to use the Format32PArgb format.  It is about 10 times faster than any other format.  Load the images into a Bitmap with the right format first."

Answer (score 0):

If you have a LOT of items (Maybe realized as controls), forget about the standard event mechanism of Windows Forms. Some time ago, i've written a logic gate editor/simulator which supported lots of thousands of gates in the editor and was really fast. There, I've used the canvas and draw the gates as custom "images" instead of putting them as controls. You'll have to write a custom `GetUnderlyingGate` function which resolves the current gate / tile (Is your editor a tilemap editor?) from a coordinate array. Also, there were some visible area optimizations.

Maybe, when i'm back home, I'll upload some sourcecode and notify you.